# Why isn't tailwind CSS working on the card component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Whenever I delete something off of the css for the card component and readd it, it works but whenever I restart my project, it stops working.

I've already tried adding the html directory file to the content section of the tailwind.config file.

What it is supposed to look like:

[image]

How it is looking:

[image]

In `src/index.css`:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap');

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

In `src/app.js`:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { HashLink as Link } from "react-router-hash-link";
import Header from "./pages/Header";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Resume from "./pages/Resume";
import Projects from "./pages/projects";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import Card from "./card/card"


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header/>
      <About/> 
      <Resume/>
      <Card
        img = "./img/resume.png"
        title = "Resume"
        description = "d resume"
        button = "download"
      />
      <Projects/>
      <Contact/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App;
```

In `src/card/card.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
export default function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div class="min-h-screen bg-orange-100  " className="card"> 
      <div
        class="w-60 p-2 bg-white rounded-xl transform transition-all hover:-translate-y-2 duration-300 shadow-lg hover:shadow-2xl"
        className="card_body"
      >
        <img class="h-40 object-cover rounded-xl" src={props.img} />
        <div class="p-2"></div>
        <h2 class="font-bold text-lg mb-2 " className="card_title">
          {props.title}
        </h2>
        <p class="text-sm text-gray-600" className="card_description">
          {props.description}
        </p>
        <div class="m-2">
          <button
            class="text-white bg-sky-500 px-3 py-1 rounded-md hover:bg-purple-700"
            className="card_btn"
          >
            {props.button}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In `tailwind.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  purge: ["*"],
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./*/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        inter: "Inter",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: What are you using? CRA, Next.js, etc.

Comment: @Camilo reactjs

Comment: I know, but how did you scafold the project? Did you manually setup everything or have you used something like create-react-app?

Comment: I used create-react-app @Camilo

Comment: Looks like you are mixing `class` and `className`. In React you should always use `className`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never import the CSS file. Try adding `import "./index.css"` in the `src/App.js` file

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work when I got rid of all of the "className" on ./card/card but I am not sure why.